# Color a mesh by height and width

Tags: python, 3d, vtk, colormap

[image]I am trying to color an object based on the width of this later.

Thank you

I tried to inspire myself from this [code](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Meshes/ColoredElevationMap/) But this later is for the height. And I want to set a color map based on the width for each z-slice, like the figure below

Comment: Nice plot. I have never used the `vtk` library directly, so I cannot help there. However, I could easily provide working code in Mayavi, or maybe even Matplotlib.

Comment: Can you please provide to me a code in matplotlib ? I am strugling ..
Thank you

Comment: Sure, please post the input data needed to make the plot (or a link to it in Github, etc.). Ideally, the data should be in the format that is easiest to understand.

Comment: THank you very much.
-  [Nifti File](https://github.com/HamidFsian/References/blob/master/jonathanfnissen_airways_with_pathology_new_model_75.nii.gz)
- [STL file](https://github.com/HamidFsian/References/blob/master/airways_no_labels.stl)

Can you please let me see the code you will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vedo:

```bash
pip install -U git+https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo.git
```

then (ignore printouts)

```py
from vedo import *

m = Mesh("airways_no_labels.stl").decimate(0.1)
pts = m.points()

lns=[]
for z in pts[:,2]:
    ln = m.intersect_with_plane([0,0,z], [0,0,1])
    if ln.npoints:
        lns.append(ln.average_size())
    else:
        lns.append(0.0)
        
m.cmap("RdYlGn", lns, vmin=15).add_scalarbar(size=(50,400))
show(m, axes=1, size=(700,1200), elevation=-90)
```

[image]